# Use the entry in a SSH alias into a PHP script

Tags: php, ssh

I have an SSH alias in `bash_profile` for `sser` that runs a PHP script. I need to use the entry after `sser` in the script. For example:

```
# sser example.com
```

How do I call the entry for `example.com` in my script?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. What do you mean  for 'entry after sser'? Call the entry?

Comment: I mean the 'domain.com' part. I want to substitute it with any string when typing the command, and to call that string in the php script. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Your variable will be in `$argv[1]`